# How to parse multiple nested sub-commands using python argparse?

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, argparse

I am implementing a command line program which has interface like this:

```
cmd [GLOBAL_OPTIONS] {command [COMMAND_OPTS]} [{command [COMMAND_OPTS]} ...]
```

I have gone through the [argparse documentation](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html). I can implement `GLOBAL_OPTIONS` as optional argument using `add_argument` in `argparse`. And the `{command [COMMAND_OPTS]}` using [Sub-commands](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#sub-commands).

From the documentation it seems I can have only one sub-command. But as you can see I have to implement one or more sub-commands. What is the best way to parse such command line arguments useing `argparse`?

Comment: I don't think this is what sub-commands is intended for. From the documentation it states that this is, in essence, for controlling separate distinct *subprograms*. Have you looked into [argument groups](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#argument-groups)?

Comment: distutils `./setup.py` also has this style CLI interface, would be interesting to look into their source code.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

@mgilson has a nice [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10449310/446386) to this question. But problem with splitting sys.argv myself is that I lose the nice help message `Argparse` generates for the user. So I ended up doing this:

```
import argparse

## This function takes the 'extra' attribute from global namespace and
## re-parses it to create separate namespaces for all other chained commands.
def parse_extra (parser, namespace):
  namespaces = []
  extra = namespace.extra
  while extra:
    n = parser.parse_args(extra)
    extra = n.extra
    namespaces.append(n)

  return namespaces

argparser=argparse.ArgumentParser()
subparsers = argparser.add_subparsers(help='sub-command help', dest='subparser_name')

parser_a = subparsers.add_parser('command_a', help = "command_a help")
## Setup options for parser_a

## Add nargs="*" for zero or more other commands
argparser.add_argument('extra', nargs = "*", help = 'Other commands')

## Do similar stuff for other sub-parsers
```

Now after first parse all chained commands are stored in `extra`. I reparse it while it is not empty to get all the chained commands and create separate namespaces for them. And i get nicer usage string that argparse generates.

Comment: @Flavius, after I get `namespace` from the parser by calling `namespace = argparser.parse_args()`, I call `parse_extra` with `parser` and `namespace`. `extra_namespaces = parse_extra( argparser, namespace )`

Comment: I think I understand the logic, but what is `parser` in the code that you have. I only see it being used to add the `extra` argument. Then you mentioned it again in the above comment. Is it supposed to be `argparser`?

Comment: @jmlopez yeah it should be `argparser`. Will edit it.

Comment: Note that this solution fails for subcommand-specific optional arguments. See my solution below (https://stackoverflow.com/a/49977713/428542) for an alternative solution.

Comment: Here is an example of how this fails. Add the following 3 lines:
`parser_b = subparsers.add_parser('command_b', help='command_b help')`;
`parser_b.add_argument('--baz', choices='XYZ', help='baz help')`;
`options = argparser.parse_args(['--foo', 'command_a', 'command_b', '--baz', 'Z'])`;
This fails with an error `PROG: error: unrecognized arguments: --baz Z`. The reason is that during the parsing of `command_a`, the optional arguments of `command_b` are already parsed (and are unknown for the subparser of `command_a`).

Comment: I was able to work with `import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--bar', type=int, help='bar help')
parser.add_argument('commands', nargs='*', metavar='COMMAND',
                 choices=['command_a', 'command_b'])`

Answer (score 40):

I came up with the same qustion, and it seems i have got a better answer.

The solution is we shall not simply nest subparser with another subparser, but we can add subparser following with a parser following another subparser.

Here is code to show this:

```
parent_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
parent_parser.add_argument('--user', '-u',
                    default=getpass.getuser(),
                    help='username')
parent_parser.add_argument('--debug', default=False, required=False,
                        action='store_true', dest="debug", help='debug flag')
main_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
service_subparsers = main_parser.add_subparsers(title="service",
                    dest="service_command")
service_parser = service_subparsers.add_parser("first", help="first",
                    parents=[parent_parser])
action_subparser = service_parser.add_subparsers(title="action",
                    dest="action_command")
action_parser = action_subparser.add_parser("second", help="second",
                    parents=[parent_parser])

args = main_parser.parse_args()
```

Comment: Yes, `argparse` does allow nested subparsers.  But I've only seen them used in one other place - in a test case for a Python issue, http://bugs.python.org/issue14365

Comment: This assumes that the commands have a nested structure.  But the question is asking for "parallel" commands

Comment: I am trying to create multiple subparsers like `service` in this case since I demarcation of commands. It errs out saying I cannot have duplicate commands? I want some thing like this `command --user us pass --debug false subcommandone subcommandoption` or `command --user us pass --debug false subcommandtwo subcommandoption` or `commandtwo --user us pass subcommandthree subcommandoption`. I intend to add complete help docs accordingly also. The code will be run as `python test.py command --user us pass --debug false subcommandtwo subcommandoption`

Answer (score 18):

`parse_known_args` returns a Namespace and a list of unknown strings.  This is similar to the `extra` in the checked answer.

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--foo')
sub = parser.add_subparsers()
for i in range(1,4):
    sp = sub.add_parser('cmd%i'%i)
    sp.add_argument('--foo%i'%i) # optionals have to be distinct

rest = '--foo 0 cmd2 --foo2 2 cmd3 --foo3 3 cmd1 --foo1 1'.split() # or sys.argv
args = argparse.Namespace()
while rest:
    args,rest =  parser.parse_known_args(rest,namespace=args)
    print args, rest
```

produces:

```
Namespace(foo='0', foo2='2') ['cmd3', '--foo3', '3', 'cmd1', '--foo1', '1']
Namespace(foo='0', foo2='2', foo3='3') ['cmd1', '--foo1', '1']
Namespace(foo='0', foo1='1', foo2='2', foo3='3') []
```

An alternative loop would give each subparser its own namespace.  This allows overlap in positionals names.

```
argslist = []
while rest:
    args,rest =  parser.parse_known_args(rest)
    argslist.append(args)
```

Comment: Works nicely. There is a flaw however: if there is a misspelled option somewhere (e.g. `rest = '--foo 0 cmd2 --foo2 2 --bar cmd3 --foo3 3 cmd1 --foo1 1'.split()`), then argparse will end in `error: too few arguments` instead of pointing out the invalid option. This is because the bad option will be left in `rest` until we are out of command arguments.

Comment: The comment `# or sys.argv` should be `# or sys.argv[1:]`.

Answer (score 17):

The solution provide by @Vikas fails for subcommand-specific optional arguments, but the approach is valid. Here is an improved version:

```
import argparse

# create the top-level parser
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='PROG')
parser.add_argument('--foo', action='store_true', help='foo help')
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(help='sub-command help', dest='subparser_name')

# create the parser for the "command_a" command
parser_a = subparsers.add_parser('command_a', help='command_a help')
parser_a.add_argument('bar', type=int, help='bar help')

# create the parser for the "command_b" command
parser_b = subparsers.add_parser('command_b', help='command_b help')
parser_b.add_argument('--baz', choices='XYZ', help='baz help')

# parse some argument lists
argv = ['--foo', 'command_a', '12', 'command_b', '--baz', 'Z']
while argv:
    print(argv)
    options, argv = parser.parse_known_args(argv)
    print(options)
    if not options.subparser_name:
        break
```

This uses `parse_known_args` instead of `parse_args`. `parse_args` aborts as soon as a argument unknown to the current subparser is encountered, `parse_known_args` returns them as a second value in the returned tuple.  In this approach, the remaining arguments are fed again to the parser. So for each command, a new Namespace is created.

Note that in this basic example, all global options are added to the first options Namespace only, not to the subsequent Namespaces.

This approach works fine for most situations, but has three important limitations:

- It is not possible to use the same optional argument for different subcommands, like `myprog.py command_a --foo=bar command_b --foo=bar`.
- It is not possible to use any variable length positional arguments with subcommands (`nargs='?'` or `nargs='+'` or `nargs='*'`).
- Any known argument is parsed, without 'breaking' at the new command. E.g. in `PROG --foo command_b command_a --baz Z 12` with the above code, `--baz Z` will be consumed by `command_b`, not by `command_a`.

These limitations are a direct limitation of argparse. Here is a simple example that shows the limitations of argparse -even when using a single subcommand-:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('spam', nargs='?')
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(help='sub-command help', dest='subparser_name')

# create the parser for the "command_a" command
parser_a = subparsers.add_parser('command_a', help='command_a help')
parser_a.add_argument('bar', type=int, help='bar help')

# create the parser for the "command_b" command
parser_b = subparsers.add_parser('command_b', help='command_b help')

options = parser.parse_args('command_a 42'.split())
print(options)
```

This will raise the `error: argument subparser_name: invalid choice: '42' (choose from 'command_a', 'command_b')`.

The cause is that the internal method `argparse.ArgParser._parse_known_args()` it is too greedy and assumes that `command_a` is the value of the optional `spam` argument. In particular, when 'splitting' up optional and positional arguments, `_parse_known_args()` does not look at the names of the arugments (like `command_a` or `command_b`), but merely where they occur in the argument list. It also assumes that any subcommand will consume all remaining arguments.
This limitation of `argparse` also prevents a proper implementation of multi-command subparsers. This unfortunately means that a proper implementation requires a full rewrite of the `argparse.ArgParser._parse_known_args()` method, which is 200+ lines of code.

Given these limitation, it may be an options to simply revert to a single multiple-choice argument instead of subcommands:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--bar', type=int, help='bar help')
parser.add_argument('commands', nargs='*', metavar='COMMAND',
                 choices=['command_a', 'command_b'])

options = parser.parse_args('--bar 2 command_a command_b'.split())
print(options)
#options = parser.parse_args(['--help'])
```

It is even possible to list the different commands in the usage information, see my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/49999185/428542

Answer (score 6):

Improving on the answer by @mgilson, I wrote a small parsing method which splits argv into parts and puts values of arguments of commands into hierarchy of namespaces:

```
import sys
import argparse


def parse_args(parser, commands):
    # Divide argv by commands
    split_argv = [[]]
    for c in sys.argv[1:]:
        if c in commands.choices:
            split_argv.append([c])
        else:
            split_argv[-1].append(c)
    # Initialize namespace
    args = argparse.Namespace()
    for c in commands.choices:
        setattr(args, c, None)
    # Parse each command
    parser.parse_args(split_argv[0], namespace=args)  # Without command
    for argv in split_argv[1:]:  # Commands
        n = argparse.Namespace()
        setattr(args, argv[0], n)
        parser.parse_args(argv, namespace=n)
    return args


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
commands = parser.add_subparsers(title='sub-commands')

cmd1_parser = commands.add_parser('cmd1')
cmd1_parser.add_argument('--foo')

cmd2_parser = commands.add_parser('cmd2')
cmd2_parser.add_argument('--foo')

cmd2_parser = commands.add_parser('cmd3')
cmd2_parser.add_argument('--foo')


args = parse_args(parser, commands)
print(args)
```

It behaves properly, providing nice argparse help:

For `./test.py --help`:

```
usage: test.py [-h] {cmd1,cmd2,cmd3} ...

optional arguments:
  -h, --help        show this help message and exit

sub-commands:
  {cmd1,cmd2,cmd3}
```

For `./test.py cmd1 --help`:

```
usage: test.py cmd1 [-h] [--foo FOO]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
  --foo FOO
```

And creates a hierarchy of namespaces containing the argument values:

```
./test.py cmd1 --foo 3 cmd3 --foo 4
Namespace(cmd1=Namespace(foo='3'), cmd2=None, cmd3=Namespace(foo='4'))
```

Comment: Reviewing your code above, I ran into one problem. On line 18,  you refer to `split_argv[0]` which is actually empty in `split_argv`, because you append `[c]` to `split_argv` (intially set to `[[]]`). If you change line 7 to `split_argv = []`, everything works as expected.

Comment: I did some more fixes (again) to the code you shared (fixing some issues I was running into) and ended up with this: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f4be805fc3ff9e132eb1e1aa0b4f7d4b

Comment: This answer is pretty decent, you can determine which `subparser` was used by adding dest to the `add_subparsers` method https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8250010/argparse-identify-which-subparser-was-used/9286586#9286586

Answer (score 5):

You can always split up the command-line yourself (split `sys.argv` on your command names), and then only pass the portion corresponding to the particular command to `parse_args` -- You can even use the same `Namespace` using the namespace keyword if you want.

Grouping the commandline is easy with `itertools.groupby`:

```
import sys
import itertools
import argparse    

mycommands=['cmd1','cmd2','cmd3']

def groupargs(arg,currentarg=[None]):
    if(arg in mycommands):currentarg[0]=arg
    return currentarg[0]

commandlines=[list(args) for cmd,args in intertools.groupby(sys.argv,groupargs)]

#setup parser here...
parser=argparse.ArgumentParser()
#...

namespace=argparse.Namespace()
for cmdline in commandlines:
    parser.parse_args(cmdline,namespace=namespace)

#Now do something with namespace...
```

*untested*

Comment: Thanks mgilson. This is a nice solution to my question, but i ended up doing it little differently. I added another [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10579924/446386).

Comment: Nice use of `itertools.groupby()`! [This](https://github.com/ALLTERCO/cc3200tool/blob/46ec7281a50bc7ee03f733f6fc1d2a4d5640d4cb/cc3200tool/cc.py#L667) is how I did the same thing before I knew  about `groupby()`.

Answer (score 5):

You could try [arghandler](https://github.com/druths/arghandler).  This is an extension to argparse with explicit support for subcommands.

Comment: arghandler provides a nice way for declaring subcommands. However I don't see how this helps to solver OP's question: parsing _multiple_ subcommands. The first subcommand parsed will eat up all remaining arguments, so further commands will never be parsed. Please give a hint on how to solve this with arghandler. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Built a full Python 2/3 example with [subparsers](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.add_subparsers), [`parse_known_args`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.parse_known_args) and [`parse_args`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.parse_args) ([running on IDEone](https://ideone.com/sjfZY7)):

```py
from __future__ import print_function

from argparse import ArgumentParser
from random import randint


def main():
    parser = get_parser()

    input_sum_cmd = ['sum_cmd', '--sum']
    input_min_cmd = ['min_cmd', '--min']

    args, rest = parser.parse_known_args(
        # `sum`
        input_sum_cmd +
        ['-a', str(randint(21, 30)),
         '-b', str(randint(51, 80))] +
        # `min`
        input_min_cmd +
        ['-y', str(float(randint(64, 79))),
         '-z', str(float(randint(91, 120)) + .5)]
    )

    print('args:\t ', args,
          '\nrest:\t ', rest, '\n', sep='')

    sum_cmd_result = args.sm((args.a, args.b))
    print(
        'a:\t\t {:02d}\n'.format(args.a),
        'b:\t\t {:02d}\n'.format(args.b),
        'sum_cmd: {:02d}\n'.format(sum_cmd_result), sep='')

    assert rest[0] == 'min_cmd'
    args = parser.parse_args(rest)
    min_cmd_result = args.mn((args.y, args.z))
    print(
        'y:\t\t {:05.2f}\n'.format(args.y),
        'z:\t\t {:05.2f}\n'.format(args.z),
        'min_cmd: {:05.2f}'.format(min_cmd_result), sep='')

def get_parser():
    # create the top-level parser
    parser = ArgumentParser(prog='PROG')
    subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(help='sub-command help')

    # create the parser for the "sum" command
    parser_a = subparsers.add_parser('sum_cmd', help='sum some integers')
    parser_a.add_argument('-a', type=int,
                          help='an integer for the accumulator')
    parser_a.add_argument('-b', type=int,
                          help='an integer for the accumulator')
    parser_a.add_argument('--sum', dest='sm', action='store_const',
                          const=sum, default=max,
                          help='sum the integers (default: find the max)')

    # create the parser for the "min" command
    parser_b = subparsers.add_parser('min_cmd', help='min some integers')
    parser_b.add_argument('-y', type=float,
                          help='an float for the accumulator')
    parser_b.add_argument('-z', type=float,
                          help='an float for the accumulator')
    parser_b.add_argument('--min', dest='mn', action='store_const',
                          const=min, default=0,
                          help='smallest integer (default: 0)')
    return parser


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2):

I had more or less the same requirements: Being able to set global arguments and being able to chain commands and **execute them in order of command line**.

I ended up with the following code. I did use some parts of the code from this and other threads.

```
# argtest.py
import sys
import argparse

def init_args():

    def parse_args_into_namespaces(parser, commands):
        '''
        Split all command arguments (without prefix, like --) in
        own namespaces. Each command accepts extra options for
        configuration.
        Example: `add 2 mul 5 --repeat 3` could be used to a sequencial
                 addition of 2, then multiply with 5 repeated 3 times.
        '''
        class OrderNamespace(argparse.Namespace):
            '''
            Add `command_order` attribute - a list of command
            in order on the command line. This allows sequencial
            processing of arguments.
            '''
            globals = None
            def __init__(self, **kwargs):
                self.command_order = []
                super(OrderNamespace, self).__init__(**kwargs)

            def __setattr__(self, attr, value):
                attr = attr.replace('-', '_')
                if value and attr not in self.command_order:
                    self.command_order.append(attr)
                super(OrderNamespace, self).__setattr__(attr, value)

        # Divide argv by commands
        split_argv = [[]]
        for c in sys.argv[1:]:
            if c in commands.choices:
                split_argv.append([c])
            else:
                split_argv[-1].append(c)

        # Globals arguments without commands
        args = OrderNamespace()
        cmd, args_raw = 'globals', split_argv.pop(0)
        args_parsed = parser.parse_args(args_raw, namespace=OrderNamespace())
        setattr(args, cmd, args_parsed)

        # Split all commands to separate namespace
        pos = 0
        while len(split_argv):
            pos += 1
            cmd, *args_raw = split_argv.pop(0)
            assert cmd[0].isalpha(), 'Command must start with a letter.'
            args_parsed = commands.choices[cmd].parse_args(args_raw, namespace=OrderNamespace())
            setattr(args, f'{cmd}~{pos}', args_parsed)

        return args


    #
    # Supported commands and options
    #
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter)

    parser.add_argument('--print', action='store_true')

    commands = parser.add_subparsers(title='Operation chain')

    cmd1_parser = commands.add_parser('add', formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter)
    cmd1_parser.add_argument('add', help='Add this number.', type=float)
    cmd1_parser.add_argument('-r', '--repeat', help='Repeat this operation N times.',
                                               default=1, type=int)

    cmd2_parser = commands.add_parser('mult', formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter)
    cmd2_parser.add_argument('mult', help='Multiply with this number.', type=float)
    cmd2_parser.add_argument('-r', '--repeat', help='Repeat this operation N times.',
                                               default=1, type=int)

    args = parse_args_into_namespaces(parser, commands)
    return args


#
# DEMO
#

args = init_args()

# print('Parsed arguments:')
# for cmd in args.command_order:
#     namespace = getattr(args, cmd)
#     for option_name in namespace.command_order:
#         option_value = getattr(namespace, option_name)
#         print((cmd, option_name, option_value))

print('Execution:')
result = 0
for cmd in args.command_order:
    namespace = getattr(args, cmd)
    cmd_name, cmd_position = cmd.split('~') if cmd.find('~') > -1 else (cmd, 0)
    if cmd_name == 'globals':
        pass
    elif cmd_name == 'add':
        for r in range(namespace.repeat):
            if args.globals.print:
                print(f'+ {namespace.add}')
            result = result + namespace.add
    elif cmd_name == 'mult':
        for r in range(namespace.repeat):
            if args.globals.print:
                print(f'* {namespace.mult}')
            result = result * namespace.mult
    else:
        raise NotImplementedError(f'Namespace `{cmd}` is not implemented.')
print(10*'-')
print(result)
```

Below an example:

```
$ python argstest.py --print add 1 -r 2 mult 5 add 3 mult -r 5 5

Execution:
+ 1.0
+ 1.0
* 5.0
+ 3.0
* 5.0
* 5.0
* 5.0
* 5.0
* 5.0
----------
40625.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Another package which supports parallel parsers is "declarative_parser".

```
import argparse
from declarative_parser import Parser, Argument

supported_formats = ['png', 'jpeg', 'gif']

class InputParser(Parser):
    path = Argument(type=argparse.FileType('rb'), optional=False)
    format = Argument(default='png', choices=supported_formats)

class OutputParser(Parser):
    format = Argument(default='jpeg', choices=supported_formats)

class ImageConverter(Parser):
    description = 'This app converts images'

    verbose = Argument(action='store_true')
    input = InputParser()
    output = OutputParser()

parser = ImageConverter()

commands = '--verbose input image.jpeg --format jpeg output --format gif'.split()

namespace = parser.parse_args(commands)
```

and namespace becomes:

```
Namespace(
    input=Namespace(format='jpeg', path=<_io.BufferedReader name='image.jpeg'>),
    output=Namespace(format='gif'),
    verbose=True
)
```

Disclaimer: I am the author. Requires Python 3.6. To install use:

```
pip3 install declarative_parser
```

Here is the [documentation](http://declarative-parser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and here is the [repo on GitHub](https://github.com/krassowski/declarative-parser).

Answer (score 0):

In order to parse the sub commands, I used the following (referred from argparse.py code). It parses the sub parser arguments and retains the help for both. Nothing additional passed there.

```
args, _ = parser.parse_known_args()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this multicommand-arg-parser I wrote.
It's easy to use, write your template in json format and apply the parser.

https://github.com/antoniofrs/multicommand-args-parser

For example:

```
[
    {
        "id": "c1_id",
        "command": "command1",
        "help": "Select c1",
        "args": [ ],
        "subCommands": [
            {
                "id": "sc1_id",
                "command": "subcommand1",
                "help": "select sc1",
                "args": [ ]
            },
            {
                "id": "sc2_id",
                "command": "subcommand2",
                "help": "Select c12",
                "args": [ ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "c1_id",
        "command": "command2",
        "help": "Selected c2",
        "args": [ ]
    }
]
```

Creates the following structure:

> command1 --my-args-here
> command1 subcommand1 --my-args-here
> command1 subcommand2 --my-args-here
> command2 --my-args-here

Where `id`, which you can retrieve from `agrs.command_id`, will help you to get the command given in input by the user.

You can specify the list of args in the appropriate field (Check the repository readme).

Remember that subcommands inherit command arguments.
(e.g `subcommand1` contains also the arguments of `command`)

The json structure is recursive so you can create as many levels of subcommands as you like

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35161908)

Answer (score 0):

The currently most-voted answer's code isn't reproducible.

In the other existing answers, the command line doesn't fail if the user doesn't specify a sub-command. In my use-case, I need the program to fail if no sub-commands are passed (and ideally display the help).

So here is how to do that :

```py
import argparse
import sys


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="My command line.")
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(title="commands", dest="cmd")

evaluate_parser = subparsers.add_parser("evaluate", help="Run the evaluation using emulated keyboard.")
evaluate_parser.set_defaults(cmd="evaluate")

layout_parser = subparsers.add_parser("show_layout", help="Display the layout over the keyboard for debugging purpose.")
layout_parser.set_defaults(cmd="show_layout")

args = parser.parse_args()

if args.cmd is None:
    parser.print_help(sys.stderr)
    sys.exit(1)
```

Answer (score -4):

you can use the package optparse

```
import optparse
parser = optparse.OptionParser()
parser.add_option("-f", dest="filename", help="corpus filename")
parser.add_option("--alpha", dest="alpha", type="float", help="parameter alpha", default=0.5)
(options, args) = parser.parse_args()
fname = options.filename
alpha = options.alpha
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. Also, optparse is deprecated (from the [python docs](http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html) "The optparse module is deprecated and will not be developed further; development will continue with the argparse module").

Comment: Sorry for downvote, but this is not addressing the question i asked.