# Mimicking AWS CLI / gcloud command line args

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line-interface, command-line-arguments, argparse

I have utility scripts for interfacing with Auth0. I want to combine them into a single tool similar to gcloud and awscli:

```
$ gcloud [module] [commands & args]
$ aws cloudformation validate-template --template-body file://test.yml

$ auth0 user add --email [EMAIL] ...
$ auth0 connection backup --connection [CXD_ID]
$ auth0 [user | connection | client | ...]
```

I don't think I can do this with argparse as it treats args w/o the leading dash(es) as mandatory positional args, but I am certainly not an expert.

Comment: Maybe subcommands? https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#sub-commands

Comment: That's it. Or I think that's it. In all my searching I never thought to search for "sub commands". Thanks!

Comment: No problem. I'm not sure if third-party is an option but if so, you might want to look into click too: http://click.pocoo.org/6/commands/

Comment: From your sample it's not entirely clear which strings are keys (or flags) with-or-without the prefix, and which are names for strings.

Answer (score 0):

@delirious-lettuce provided the answer: sub-commands in argparse. Lesson learned: Read *all* the documentation before posting to SO.

Related:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#sub-commands

[How to parse multiple nested sub-commands using python argparse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10448200/how-to-parse-multiple-nested-sub-commands-using-python-argparse#10579924)