# Argparse optional arguments with multilevel parser/subparser

Tags: python, argparse, optional-arguments, subparsers

I have a set of parsers and subparsers to build a production or development system.
If the user picks production, he can add options and all is well.
If he pics development, he can enter an architecture and then enter build options.
This is where it gets sticky.
I want him to be able to select build option 'comms' 'server' or 'all', but if he picks server, he has more choices.

My implementation is below. I tried combinations of parsers and subpasers
(it seems that arguments can only be added to parsers, not subparsers, is that correct?)

It falls apart for 2 reasons:
1) I can only select arch or build and I need to select both
2) If I select build it always requires that I pick 'server', even if I pick one of the other two.

So I would like something like this
./buildServer.py Dev arch -arm build -comms
or
./buildServer.py Dev arch -arm build -server -tcp

I'd appreciate and help/guidance I can get - TIA

Code:

def verify():

```
main_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()     
main_subparsers = main_parser.add_subparsers(title="main", dest="main_command")          

# parser production choices                                                                                                     
prod_parser = main_subparsers.add_parser("prod", help="Prod")     
prod_parser.add_argument("-c",  "--change",   action='store_true', dest="change_sig", default=False, help="Change signature information (default = %(default)s)")
prod_parser.add_argument("-sd", "--sign-deb",  action='store_true', dest="sign_deb",   default=False, help="Add signature to the .deb file (default = %(default)s)")
prod_parser.add_argument ("-i",  "--install",  action='store_true', dest="build_deb" , default=False, help="Build .deb file from existing structure (default = %(default)s)")

# parser for development                                                                                                   
dev_parser = main_subparsers.add_parser("Dev", help="Dev")                                                                                                              
dev_subparser = dev_parser.add_subparsers(title="devsubparser")     

# optional development architecture choices
action_arch_parser = dev_subparser.add_parser("arch", help="architecture")
dev_arch_group = action_arch_parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
dev_arch_group.add_argument("-x86",  action='store_const', dest="architecture", const='x', default='x',help="Build dev code on X86")
dev_arch_group.add_argument("-arm",  action='store_const', dest="architecture",     const='a', help="Build dev code on arm")

# development build choices - 2 arguments (coms / all) and a third (server) that has its own options.
dev_build_parser = dev_subparser.add_parser("build", help="build")
dev_build_parser.add_argument("-comms", action='store_true',  help="Build comms program")
dev_build_parser.add_argument("-all", action='store_true',  help="Build all programs")
server_parser = dev_build_parser.add_subparsers(title="server", help="server subparser")
server_parser_p = server_parser.add_parser("server", help="server parser")
server_parser_p.add_argument("-tcp", help="tcp option")
server_parser_p.add_argument("-fips", help="fips option")
server_parser_p.add_argument("-sim", help="sim option")


args = main_parser.parse_args()
```

Answer (score 0):

`aparser.add_argument(...)` creates an `Action` class object, actually a subclass specified by the `action` parameter.  That action/argument may be `positional` or `optional` (flagged).

`sp=aparse.add_subparsers(...)` is specialized version of `add_argument` that creates an `Action` of the subparser class.  `print(sp)` will show some of its attributes.  This is actually a `positional` argument, with a `choices` attribute.

`p1 = sp.add_parser(...)` creates an `argparse.ArgumentParser()` object, and links it to a name that is placed in the `sp.choices` list.  The parser is returned as the `p1` variable.

`p1.add_argument(...)` defines a Action/argument, just as done with the main parser.

So during parsing, the inputs (`sys.argv`) are handled one by one, as is usual.  But when it hits a string that matches in position and name of a "p1", the parsing task is passed on to `p1` (with what remains of the `sys.argv` list).  When `p1` has reached the end of `sys.argv` its namespace and control is passed to the parent parser.  The parent doesn't do any further parsing.

In your case you can pass down through several levels of parsers.  (the terms, parser and subparsers can be a bit confusing, at least in the description.  They are clearly defined in the code.)

This subparser mechanism allows only one choice (at each level).  This isn't a multilevel tree transversal tool.  You go down one particular thread to end, and back up.

So with

./buildServer.py Dev arch -arm build -comms or ./buildServer.py Dev arch -arm build -server -tcp

```
main_parser   (sees 'Dev', passes control to:)
    dev_parser   (sees 'arch', passes control to:)
        action_arch_parser
            (sees -arm - sets the const)
            (doesn't have any positional to handle 'build'
                  returns with an unrechognized arguments)
```

There may be ways of working around this - I or others have suggested things like this in previous SO - but the straight forward `argparse` usage does not allow for multiple subparsers (just the nesting that you show).

Comment: Thanks hpaulj I appreciate the explanation.  It is very clear.  I now understand @augurar comment on How to parse multiple nested sub-commands using python argparse?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10448200/how-to-parse-multiple-nested-sub-commands-using-python-argparse/10449310#10449310 about nested and parallel commands.  Are any of the answers in that post useful for what I am trying to do?  It looks like the answer would involve splitting the argv?  Can you please point me to (hopefully not to complicated) suggestions?  Thanks again!

Comment: Is there a way to use parse_known_args and parse the server options separately?