# Django management command with dynamic arguments

Tags: python, django

How would you create a Django management command that has arguments that are dynamic depending on a positional argument?

For example, the named arguments for the command `dynamic_command` with positional argument `option1`:

```
python manage.py dynamic_command option1
```

should be different from the named arguments for the command `dynamic_command` with positional argument `option2`:

```
python manage.py dynamic_command option2
```

This is useful for cases where the underlying command handle is the same, but parameters could vary depending on the context that the command is run.

To elaborate further, you may want the command `dynamic_command option1` to accept named arguments `--kv1 --kv2`:

e.g.

```
python manage.py dynamic_command option1 --kv1 --kv2
```

but `dynamic_command option2` to accept named arguments `--kv3 --kv4`:

e.g.

```
python manage.py dynamic_command option2 --kv3 --kv4
```

Answer (score 2):

Override the `add_arguments(self, parser)` method. the `parser` argument is an `argparse.ArgumentParser` object (docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html).

You might be looking for Sub-commands/sub-parsers: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#sub-commands

Comment: Thanks! I think I can override the add_arguments method and do something like this using sub-parsers:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10448200/how-to-parse-multiple-nested-sub-commands-using-python-argparse