# Python argparse, positional arguments and subparsers

Tags: python

I have the following snippet where I am using argparse with multiple subparsers

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description = "Setup the DB",
        add_help=False)
parser.add_argument('action', type = str,
        choices=['drop','populate','print','create','print-metadata'],
        help = "Specify an action", default = None)
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()
drop_parser = subparsers.add_parser('drop',parents=[parser])
drop_parser.add_argument('-dataset-name',
        required=True,
        type = str, help = "Dataset Name",
        default = None)
.....
args = parser.parse_args()
.....
```

When I go to run this I get the following:

```
python .\populatedb.py drop -dataset-name foo
populatedb.py: error: invalid choice: 'foo' (choose from 'drop', 'populate', 'print', 'create', 'print-metadata')
```

I am wondering where the code above is going wrong. Note that the "action" argument is a positional argument.

Thank you in advance. This is my first use of subparsers I am probably making an obvious mistake.

Thank you in advance.

Regards,

Ranga

Comment: Why are you adding an argument for the subparser?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. The argument is only meaningful for the action "drop" . For other options it is not meaningful hence I added it to the subparser. I left out the other subparsers for clarity.

Comment: It feels like you might need to add 'action drop'. You can run python populatedb.py -h to see the sequence of arguments you need to pass.

Comment: python .\populatedb.py -help gives the following : usage: populatedb.py {drop,populate,print,create,print-metadata} so that does not seem to be the issue.

Comment: But generally you don't need to `add_action` _and_ add a subparser with the same name ...

Comment: @mgilson  I removed the add_argument from the parent parser and now I get further; however, how would I know which subparser got invoked in that case?

Comment: The answer is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8250010/argparse-identify-which-subparser-was-used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generally accepted thing to do here is to not have an argument for the subparser -- it is it's own argument provided by `argparse`:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description = "Setup the DB",
        add_help=False)
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()
drop_parser = subparsers.add_parser('drop',parents=[parser])
drop_parser.add_argument('-dataset-name',
        required=True,
        type = str, help = "Dataset Name",
        default = None)
.....
args = parser.parse_args()
```

Now you don't necessarily know which parser was selected but don't worry, there's a built-in mechanism for this as well.  One common use-case is having one function that should be invoked for each subparser...

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description = "Setup the DB",
        add_help=False)
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()

def drop_parser_handler(args):
    ...

drop_parser = subparsers.add_parser('drop',parents=[parser])
drop_parser.add_argument('-dataset-name',
        required=True,
        type = str, help = "Dataset Name",
        default = None)
drop_parser.set_defaults(func=drop_parser_handler)
.....

args = parser.parse_args()
args.func(args)
```

Of course you don't need to do anything this complex -- You could just set a constant value:

```
drop_parser.set_defaults(subparser_name='drop')
```

Comment: Thanks! That helped.