# Resolve argparse alias back to the original command

Tags: python, argparse

I'm using a [subparser/subcommand that has an alias](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#sub-commands).

I'm using the `dest` option for the subparser to store the name of the subcommand so I can get it later.

Currently if the subcommand's name is `reallyLongName` and the alias is `r` (say) then the `dest` option stores either `reallyLongName` *or* `r` exactly - whatever I typed in gets stored.  This is annoying because I now have to check for the name of the command ***or any of its aliases*** in order to identify the command.

Is there a way to get argparse to store the subcommand's name in the `dest` field in some sort of single, canonical text string?

For example, given the following code:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(dest='command', help='sub-command help')

parser_ag = subparsers.add_parser(  'mySubcommand',
                                    aliases=['m'],
                                    help='Subcommand help')

print(parser.parse_args('mySubcommand'.split()))

print(parser.parse_args('m'.split()))
```

the following output is produced:

```
Namespace(command='mySubcommand')
Namespace(command='m')
```

Desired result: `command` has a single, canonical value for both, for example:

```
Namespace(command='mySubcommand')
Namespace(command='mySubcommand')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was surprisingly difficult to dig out.  When you add a subparser, it gets stored in the parents `._actions` attribute.  From there it is just digging through attributes to get what you need.  Below I create dictionaries to reference the subparser arguments by the dest name, and then added a function that lets us remap the inputted arguments to the primary argument name.

```py
from collections import defaultdict

def get_subparser_aliases(parser, dest):
    out = defaultdict(list)
    prog_str = parser.prog
    dest_dict = {a.dest: a for a in parser._actions}
    try:
        choices = dest_dict.get(dest).choices
    except AttributeError:
        raise AttributeError(f'The parser "{parser}" has no subparser with a `dest` of "{dest}"')

    for k, v in choices.items():
        clean_v = v.prog.replace(prog_str, '', 1).strip()
        out[clean_v].append(k)
    return dict(out)

def remap_args(args, mapping, dest):
    setattr(args, dest, mapping.get(getattr(args, dest)))
    return args
```

Using your example, we can remap the parse args using:

```py
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(dest='command', help='sub-command help')
parser_ag = subparsers.add_parser('mySubcommand',
                                  aliases=['m'],
                                  help='Subcommand help')

args = parser.parse_args('m'.split())
mapping = get_subparser_aliases(parser, 'command')
remap_args(args, mapping, 'command')
print(args)
# prints:
Namespace(command='mySubcommand')
```

Here is an example of it at work with multiple subparser levels..  We have a parser with an optional argument and a subparser.  The subparser has 3 possible arguments, the last of which invoke another subparser (a sub-subparser), with 2 possible arguments.

You can examine either the top level parser or the first level subparser to see alias mappings.

```py
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--someoption', '-s', action='store_true')

subparser1 = parser.add_subparsers(help='sub-command help', dest='sub1')
parser_r = subparser1.add_parser('reallyLongName', aliases=['r'])
parser_r.add_argument('foo', type=int, help='foo help')
parser_s = subparser1.add_parser('otherReallyLong', aliases=['L'])
parser_s.add_argument('bar', choices='abc', help='bar help')
parser_z = subparser1.add_parser('otherOptions', aliases=['oo'])

subparser2 = parser_z.add_subparsers(help='sub-sub-command help', dest='sub2')
parser_x = subparser2.add_parser('xxx', aliases=['x'])
parser_x.add_argument('fizz', type=float, help='fizz help')
parser_y = subparser2.add_parser('yyy', aliases=['y'])
parser_y.add_argument('blip', help='blip help')

get_subparser_aliases(parser, 'sub1')
# returns:
{'reallyLongName': ['reallyLongName', 'r'],
 'otherReallyLong': ['otherReallyLong', 'L'],
 'otherOptions': ['otherOptions', 'oo']}

get_subparser_aliases(parser_z, 'sub2')
# returns:
{'xxx': ['xxx', 'x'], 'yyy': ['yyy', 'y']}
```

Using this with the function above, we can remap the collected args to their longer names.

```py
args = parser.parse_args('-s oo x 1.23'.split())
print(args)
# prints:
Namespace(fizz=1.23, someoption=True, sub1='oo', sub2='x')

for p, dest in zip((parser, parser_z), ('sub1', 'sub2')):
    mapping = get_subparser_aliases(p, dest)
    remap_args(args, mapping, dest)

print(args)
# prints:
Namespace(fizz=1.23, someoption=True, sub1='otherOptions', sub2='xxx')
```

Comment: `choices = subparsers.choices` will simplify the search a bit.  `subparsers` is the `argparse._SubParsersAction` class object.  You are pulling the full or base name out of the `prog` which is used in the subparser `help`.  Otherwise, `argparse` doesn't treat the subparser name as anything special.  It is just one of the aliases.

Comment: 'subparsers._name_parser_map' is the same map as `subparsers.choices`.

Answer (score 7):

There was a Python bug/issue requesting this - saving the 'base' name, rather than the alias.  You can't change that without changing `argparse.py` code.  I think the change would limited to the `Action` subclass that handles subparsers.  https://bugs.python.org/issue36664

But I point out that there's simpler way of handling this.  Just use `set_defaults` as documented near the end of the https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#sub-commands section.  There

```
parser_foo.set_defaults(func=foo)
```

is used to set a subparser specific function, but it could just as well be used to set the 'base' name.

```
parser_foo.set_defaults(name='theIncrediblyLongAlias')
```